# Loading scene plugins in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

A newbie in Phaser. I'm using Phaser 3.16.2 and the plugins from https://github.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes.

When I load a plugin in the preload() method of the first scene (Docs) and then I use it in the same scene in the create() method, it works ok. But if I change the scene (to Docs2) and I try to use the plugin in it, I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.rexUI is undefined
```

I see in the console logs that the plugin is loaded in both scenes.

```
class Docs extends Phaser.Scene {

constructor() {
    super({key: 'Docs'})
}

init(data) {
}

preload() {     
    console.log(this);
    this.load.scenePlugin({
        key: 'rexuiplugin',
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/plugins/dist/rexuiplugin.min.js',
        sceneKey: 'rexUI'
    });
}

create() {
    this.backButton = new Button(this, 50, 50, 'btn-start', this.goDocs2, 'goDocs2');
    var itemInfoRect = this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(96, 96, 50, 50, 0, COLOR_DARKEST);
}   

goDocs2() {
    this.scene.start('Docs2');
}
}


class Docs2 extends Phaser.Scene {

constructor() {
    super({key: 'Docs2'})
}

init() {

}

preload() {     
    console.log(this);
}

create() {
    var itemInfoRect = this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(96, 96, 50, 50, 0, COLOR_LIGHT);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's an open bug. There is a workaround:

https://github.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/issues/10